# .htaccess redirect to maintenance page automatically

Tags: html, .htaccess

I was wondering if in the .htaccess file I could have a check to see if a website is down. I found something that will redirect it to the maintenance mode but I don't want to have to go in and add that every time. I have a script that will run and update my live site from a repository. Is there a way to detect this update and automatically put the site in maintenance mode?

```
#This will redirect the site to maint mode/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maint\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/maint.html [R=307,L]
```

Comment: Clarify "down". To me down would likely refer to server/daemon state in which case you couldn't display anything. If you are referring to the site being in "maintenance" mode. It is only that way if you set it as such, so no you couldn't do .htaccess to detect what you have not already done.

Comment: You could have your update script write a .htaccess file for you perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script can create a file when it starts and you can check file existence in htaccess and redirect. When the script finishes - it will delete the file.

```
RewriteCond some_unique_name -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maint\.html$
RewriteRule .* http://website.com/maint.html [R=307,L]
```

No need for brackets here.